# Android Layouy background image causing choppy animation

Tags: android, animation

I have LinearLayout with background property set to drawable resource and with in that layout I have 3 buttons with custom font and also background property set to drawable resource. On click of the button I have set layout animation on buttons via anim resource. With the main background on animation is somehow choppy, jerky, not smooth but when I delete background image the animation is very smooth and stable. In the hierarchy view I noticed that layout with background image has drawing time about 17 ms. Do anyone had this kind of issue and is there a way to make it smooth or another way around it?

Comment: what is the size of the background image?

Comment: Check that your main background image is a high resolution image?

Comment: It is the same size as the layout: 720x1230 is that too big? And if so is there another way to render full res img background and still have smooth animations?